# Add top links via extension

Tags: magento-1.9

I created extension.i need to create top link to access my custom extension page.
i don't want to change it via local.xml or changing core phtml file.

is there way to add remove top links via custom extension.
I try to using adding below to my layout.xml within default tag

```
<reference name="top.links">
<action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>New</label><url>new
</url><title>New</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>60</position></action>
</reference>
```

but it not working.

Here is my layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    <reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>Events</label>monthly/index<url>
    </url><title>Events</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>60</position></action>
    </reference>
    </default>
    <monthly_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="monthly/monthly" name="monthly" template="monthly/monthly.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </monthly_index_index>
    <monthly_index_eventcalender>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="monthly/monthly" name="monthly" template="monthly/events.phtml" />
        </reference>
  <reference name="head">

         <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/monthly.js</name></action>
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/monthly.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
    </monthly_index_eventcalender>

</layout>
```

and here is my config file

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lkwebtools_Monthly>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Lkwebtools_Monthly>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <monthly>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Lkwebtools_Monthly</module>
                    <frontName>monthly</frontName>
                </args>
            </monthly>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <monthly>
                    <file>monthly.xml</file>
                </monthly>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <monthly>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Lkwebtools_Monthly</module>
                    <frontName>monthly</frontName>
                </args>
            </monthly>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <monthly module="monthly">
                <title>Monthly Event Calender</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="monthly">
                        <title>Manage Events</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>monthly/adminhtml_monthly</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </monthly>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Lkwebtools_Monthly>
                            <title>Monthly Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </Lkwebtools_Monthly>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <monthly>
                    <file>monthly.xml</file>
                </monthly>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
    <global>
        <models>
            <monthly>
                <class>Lkwebtools_Monthly_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>monthly_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </monthly>
            <monthly_mysql4>
                <class>Lkwebtools_Monthly_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <monthly>
                        <table>monthly</table>
                    </monthly>
                </entities>
            </monthly_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <monthly_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Lkwebtools_Monthly</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </monthly_setup>
            <monthly_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </monthly_write>
            <monthly_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </monthly_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <monthly>
                <class>Lkwebtools_Monthly_Block</class>
            </monthly>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <monthly>
                <class>Lkwebtools_Monthly_Helper</class>
            </monthly>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: This information is not. show your config.xml file and specify path to those files

Comment: this is XML not HTML why you are use <br> ?

Comment: this is because of <br> tag your xml is not loaded by magento

Comment: Remove <br> tag and add this into your custom extension xml file

Comment: sorry. there hasn't br tags.it is my mistake when i typing .is i need to add header.phtml file in my extension to work this? please see edited quiz

Comment: show your config.xml file

Comment: please see edited quiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is, your layout update XML file has wrong name. It should be `monthly.xml` instead of `layout.xml` and it should be reside at `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\monthly.xml`.

After make all these changes, please clear your cache.